# Using media query to manage media item picker selected collections?

Tags: mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaquery, mpmediaitemcollection

In the iPod Library Access Guide, at page 16 (where it explains about media query usage) there is a description like this, after describing the usage for MPMediaQuery:

> You can construct your own collections as well. This can be useful,
>   for example, for managing the selections a user has made with a media
>   item picker. Note, however, that collections are not mutable.

Filtering and grouping a mediapicker selected item collection - is this really possible?
I looked at the guide thoroughly but could not find a sample for this...

Any help is appreciated - thank you very much in advance!

Comment: have you got solution for this? If so please help me too. I am searching for the some related of your question. [**Here's my question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817638/how-to-get-path-of-file-selected-using-mpmediapickercontroller)

Comment: No, unfortunately I havent. I'll keep you informed for any progress!

Comment: Shin, In have got some solution for it. Now I don't bare on URL but I using persistentID to play it again.